# Version numbers on wiki pages

Tags: 2007, versioning, wiki-pages

I currently have some additional columns on my wiki which show useful information such as 'status' and 'review frequency'. These columns show at the bottom of wiki pages, with the 'modified date' below that.

What I would quite like to do is show the 'version' column at the bottom alongside the other custom columns. Is this possible to do in Sharepoint designer or via the web interfaces? It seems strange how custom columns show automatically but there is no option to show system columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got around this by creating a new custom column, setting it to a formula and then referencing [Version Number] in the field. It now shows on all pages alongside the other custom columns.